# Does this look like loose fill Asbestos?

Tags: insulation, asbestos

I found some type of loose-fill insulation stuffed behind standard fiberglass insulation while cleaning up my basement. The home was built in 1947 and I'm not sure if what I found is Asbestos (see image below).

If it is Asbestos what the heck should I do, leave it alone? cover it? put a mask on and get rid of it myself? I'm not the owner of the house and am just renting.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Looks like cellulose. Of course, I'm looking from the other side of the internet and you shouldn't bank your health on my guess.

https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-test-for-asbestos/

Comment: Yes it does, No it does not, Maybe it does.  Which ever answer is correct having a bunch folks on the internet tell if it does or does not look like asbestos is of no value to you. **If you need a definitive answer You must have it tested**.